# How to toggle bootstrap nav menu on window resize

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, storefront

I've noticed that the bootstrap navigation menu used in many wordpress themes, including the relatively common and free Storefront WooTheme, seem to be somewhat incomplete in their functionality. One problem that I've encountered  recently is that when you resize your window such that you get a compressed nav button on the small window, then you click on that button to expand the menu (to see "Home", "Shop", etc...), and then when you resize the window back to a very large size with the nav menu still toggled open, it simply disappears because it is still in the toggled state.

So the question is how do you update your theme to fix this problem so that the menu toggles closed when you resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this to your javaScript will add an event listener to the window that triggers the toggling of the navigation button on resize:

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        alert('attachEvent - resize');
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
        container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
        button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    }
        });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        //console.log('addEventListener - resize');
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
        container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
        button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    }
        }, true);
}
else {
        //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

You can add this to the Storefront WooTheme by copying the .../themes/storefront/inc/js/navigation.js and navigation.min.js files to adir under your child theme, then add the above to that copied navigation.js file (I added it just after the button.onclick block), then copy and paste that entire file into a script condenser (available online) to minimize the script, then replace the existing contents of the navigation.min.js file in your child theme with that condensed code, and save of course.

Then, because JavaScripts in child themes do not automatically override their parent theme counterparts you must enqueue them like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse26822_script_fix', 20120207);
function wpse26822_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('storefront-navigation');
    wp_enqueue_script('my_storefront-navigation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/navigation.min.js', array('jquery'),20151110,true);
}
```

In this case, wp_enqueue_scripts was called by the parent with a priority of 20120206 (the date) and so this action is added with a priority just barely greater so that it will immediately be dequeued. Then, the enqueue statement that follows that follows is actually prioritized after that to ensure that it loads after the old one was dequeued. The "true", in this case is also important because that specifies that it is to be enqueued in the footer, which is where the parent script was first enqueued.

Comment: Oops, forgot to comment out the console.log() lines that I had added for debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Replace ".menu_class" with class of your menu ul.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){

  if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    $(".menu_class").removeAttr("style");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```